# Title of B-Movie with Evolutionary Were-Human Spirit Form?

Tags: story-identification

Remembered Details:

- Circa 2004/5 (probably) made for TV B-Movie.
- Some humans possess a "primal" form which comes from human evolutionary past, and can be unleashed in some people.
- This "primal/werehuman" form looks like a spirit/translucent form when taken.
- Alpha Male antagonist spitting image (or is) James Callis.
- Story is boiler-plate formulaic: Returned to hometown scruffy protagonist. Antagonist's blond girlfriend tired of being taken for granted. Revenge sleeps with protagonist. Antagonist Alpha-male's/warns off protagonist, who after being scratched/bitten by blond girlfriend is being transformed into werehuman/primal. Innocent girl next door from hometown who never left is still in love with protagonist. Protagonist has to save girl-next-door (who of course is also a born primal human) after he accidentally hurts her by killing Alpha-Male and feeding Alpha-Male's heart to her. She heals. They both are now primal humans/get each other.

Watched at 2AM on Stars/Cinemax late night run.

Comment: James Callis wasn't in anything that resembles this in 2004/5. Unless you're thinking of Bridget Jones 2 : http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0130536/

Comment: Richard, thanks for the reply. I combed through his IMDB profile before posting, and came up empty. Tried Alexander Siddig as well, in case I had an unusually fuzzy memory of the antagonist. Didn't find anything there either. Even looking if the movie was recorded earlier in the early 00's, no dice. The antagonist had longer hair down to his shoulders and perpetually walked with his shirt completely open in front. Sadly, doesn't contribute much to the search either.

Comment: Almost sounds like a really muddled version of "Nightbreed", the 1990 movie based on Clive Barker's "Cabal", starring Craig Sheffer and David Cronenberg.